# Таймаут функции

Tags: python-3.x, settimeout

Приложение состоит из нескольких функций, при том одна из них может на долго загрузить процессор. Как сделать тайм-аут для нее? Сейчас делаю примерно следующее:

```
thread = Process(target=_send, args=(words, user_id, message, attach, _log, count,))
    thread.start()
    while thread.is_alive():
        time.sleep(5)
        if not thread.is_alive():
            break
        log_send('Зависание при отправке сообщения', 'on_send_freeze', message, user_id)
        thread.terminate()
        thread = Process(target=seps, args=(words, user_id, message, attach, _log, count,))
        thread.start()
```

Но создание процесса занимает слишком много времени (до этого "костыля" сообщение отправлялось за ~0.5 секунды, а теперь это ~1.5) и я думаю, что это через чур костыльно. Что посоветуете? 
P.S Код должен одинаково хорошо выполняться и на Linux и на Windows, так что signals отпадает

Answer (score -1):

Рецепт [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/1911548):

**timeout.py**

```
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal

class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


def timeout(seconds=10, error_message=os.strerror(errno.ETIME)):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator
```

В прикладном коде:

```
from timeout import timeout

# Десятисекундный таймаут по умолчанию
@timeout()
def long_running_function1():
    ...


# Явное указание пятисекундного таймаута
@timeout(5)
def long_running_function2():
    ...


# Тридцатисекундный таймаут завершающийся
# ошибкой "Connection timed out"
@timeout(30, os.strerror(errno.ETIMEDOUT))
def long_running_function3():
    ...
```

Увидеть в действии можно [здесь](https://repl.it/OBxZ/1).

Comment: Я пробовал такой код, но на Windows 10 с python 3.6 он не работает. Нет метода signal.signal()

Comment: В Python 3.6 [есть signal.signal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) А операционная система Python'у вообще без разницы.

Comment: В коде

@timeout()
def f():
    while True:
        print(1)


f()

Ошибка 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pibot/signal_test.py", line 34, in <module>
    f()
  File "D:/pibot/signal_test.py", line 16, in wrapper
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'

Comment: Аааа, Windows. Печально. Это тот редкий случай, когда Python не кроссплатформенный. Под Windows, на сколько мне известно, изящного и надёжного решения просто нет. Только костыли с большим оверхедом и ещё большей погрешностью.

Comment: а что есть еще?